# Django percentage form field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to use a percentage form field in Django. Basically in my models I have a float field. The default when using a model form is a text input that validates that it is a number. If the user wants to enter 40%, they must enter 0.4. What I want is an optional percentage symbol that they can enter. Therefore, they can either enter 0.4 or 40%.

Is there something like that built into Django? If not, why? I would expect this to be something that is used often. Or do I tell them it is an percentage field and force them to just fill in 40?

Comment: Not exactly what you want but have a look at http://django-extras.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/models/fields.html#percentfield

Comment: Just use the float field and put a % to the right of the input in the html/template. Or you can find the % and slice everything to the left of it then verify that it is a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create your own validator easy enough

```
def valid_pct(value):
    if value.endswith("%"):
       return float(value[:-1])/100
    else:
       try:
          return float(value)
       except ValueError:          
          raise ValidationError(
              _('%(value)s is not a valid pct'),
                params={'value': value},
           )
```

... 
**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    pct = models.StringField(validators=[valid_pct])
```